# Supporting, cheering and motivating them + is/are

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Siblings are an important part of our lives and I believe **supporting, cheering, directing and motivating them *is/are* also important**.
> 2. Booking, canceling and rebooking flights ***does/do*** not take much time.

Should I use *is/does* or *are/do* in these sentences? According to me, we can use either of them. If we are taking all these things as a single step/task then we should use *is/does*, but if we are taking these things as separate tasks/steps then we should use *are/do*. Are my interpretations correct? What should we actually use in such cases?

Answer (score 2):

In this example, we can summarise as:  "[thing] is important". Hopefully that makes it clear why we use the singular 'is' rather than the plural.

Exactly the same thing with your second example, which could be summarised as "This [thing] does not take much time."

While in both examples, [thing] does contain some plural words, the action as a whole is one single item.

Comment: Thank you :-). What if we assume those things to be separate and multiple items, can we use ‘are/do’ then?

Comment: I can't immediately think of an example where [thing] would be treated as plural, but there probably is - give me an example if you can think of one.